# Save and storage inside a App directory

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I used this code to take two images and merge in only one IMG so save inside in my camera roll, and working very well!

But how can save the same img inside the app?

Like a App/Document Directory

Here the code:

```
- (IBAction)onSavePhoto:(id)sender{

    UIImage *bottomImage = self.imageViewPick.image;
    UIImage *image       = self.scelta.image;

    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(640, 640);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );

    [bottomImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];

    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(newImage, nil, nil, nil);

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docs = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* path =  [docs stringByAppendingFormat:@"/myImage.jpg"];

NSData* imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 80)];
NSError *writeError = nil;
[imageData writeToFile:path options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&writeError];
```

If writeError is still nil after it, everything went fine, if not, it will contain the error.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `App/Document` folder and instead you should write into the folder returned from:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```